# az eventgrid event-subscription create not working in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-logic-apps, azure-cli

I'm trying to create a new eventgrid topic webhook subscription to trigger a logicapp endpoint using Azure CLI (v2.0.57) via Windows Powershell, but it's not working as expected.

I'm do the same thing on the Azure portal and also on CloudShell web interface and it's works perfectly.

The command is the follow:

`az eventgrid event-subscription create --name "sopas" --source-resource-id "/subscriptions/id/resourceGroups/name/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/name" --endpoint-type "webhook" --endpoint "https://prod-16.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/xxx/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=xxx" --debug --verbose`

The error on windows powershell is the follow:

```
az : ERROR: The attempt to validate the provided endpoint https://prod-16.westeurope.logic.azure.com/workflows/371848cd5a2242cda3f88bfcce80962a/triggers/manual/paths/invoke failed. For more details, visit 
https://aka.ms/esvalidation.
At line:3 char:1
+ az eventgrid event-subscription create --name "sopas" --source-resour ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: The atte...s/esvalidation.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

'sp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'sv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'sig' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Can someone help ?

Comment: Is the azure cli version you have older than the one installed in the cloud shell?

Comment: Hi, it's the same version. I find out that the issue is related to Powershell.